# Problem with printing via IPP

Tags: printing

I am a serious newbie to Ubuntu (and Linux in general).
I have a printer, whose connection is: dnssd://Brother%20QL-570-12c1bb._printer._tcp.local/
But the web application I am using (PHP), requires an IPP address...
Don't know where to start..!
Any help gratefully appreciated...!

regards,
Dave.

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. What is an IPP address?

Answer (score 0):

For my Brother printer, the easiest way to find its IP address was through the printer itself (ie pressing buttons on the machine rather than going through the computer) … it will depend on your model, but on mine I had to press ‘menu’ then choose ‘network’ then ‘TCP/IP’ then ‘IP address’ and it shows you directly on the printer’s LCD display.

I did try the methods in this link:

https://www.lifewire.com/find-printer-ip-address-4176356

but most of them are designed for windows and in fact didn’t work for me when I used my old windows laptop - but you might have success there.